# Map function in Ruby for Array of Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Under is my array of Object
what i wanted to is to encrypt by password using a map

```
require "bcrypt"

users = [
    { username: "user", password: "qwertyuiop" },
    { username: "user1", password: "qwertyuiop1" },
    { username: "user2", password: "qwertyuiop2" },
    { username: "user3", password: "qwertyuiop3" },
  ]

def create_hash_digest(password)
  BCrypt::Password.create(password)
end
def create_secure_users(list_of_users)
  list_of_users.map { |user_record| user_record[:password] = create_hash_digest(user_record[:password]) }
end

puts create_secure_users(users)
```

it is returning just the hashed password

Expected to return an array of same objects but with hashed passwords

```
users = [
    { username: "user", password: "hashed_password" },
    { username: "user1", password: "hashed_password" },
    { username: "user2", password: "hashed_password" },
    { username: "user3", password: "hashed_password" },
  ]
 #here hashed_password is hashed password that is saved in map
```

what I am expecting to get array of object where password is replaced with hashed password

I can achieve this with each loop but want to go with map

Comment: You don't return the entire user record in the map block.

Comment: Replace `map` with `each`. (Has side effect of modifying `users`.)

Comment: @DaveNewton do I need to use return after editing the password ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In map function the return value is final the operation,

```
def create_secure_users(list_of_users)
   list_of_users.map do |user_record|
    { username: user_record[:username], password: create_hash_digest(user_record[:password]) }
   end
end
```

or

```
def create_secure_users(list_of_users)
  list_of_users.map do |user_record|
    user_record.merge(password: create_hash_digest(user_record[:password]))
  end
end
```

do the same thing

Comment: Yes thanks that worked well I changed it a little bit for one liner some thing like this
`list_of_users.map { |user_record| user_record.merge(password: create_hash_digest(user_record[:password])) }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @safak and @DaveNewton drived 2 different approaches
using merge

```
def create_secure_users(list_of_users)
  list_of_users.map { |user_record| user_record.merge(password: create_hash_digest(user_record[:password])) }
end
```

and by returning element in map

```
def create_secure_users(list_of_users)
  list_of_users.map { |user_record|
    user_record[:password] = create_hash_digest(user_record[:password])
    user_record
  }
end
```